# Python Variable "resetting"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am setting a string to something in a function, then trying to print it in another to find that the string never changed. Am I doing something wrong?

Defining the variable at the top of my script

```
CHARNAME = "Unnamed"
```

Function setting the variable

```
def setName(name):
        CHARNAME = name
        print CHARNAME
```

Use of function

```
print CHARNAME
setName("1234")
print CHARNAME
```

Output

```
Unnamed
1234
Unnamed
```

Answer (score 13):

When you do `CHARNAME = name` in the `setName` function, you are defining it *only* for that scope. i.e, it can not be accessed outside of the function. Hence, the *global* vriable `CHARNAME` (the one with the value `"Unnamed"`), is untouched, and you proceed to print its contents after calling the function

You aren't actually overwriting the *global* variable `CHARNAME`. If you want to, you must globalise the variable `CHARNAME` in the function `setName` by putting `global CHARNAME` before you define it:

```
def setName(name):
    global CHARNAME
    CHARNAME = name
    print CHARNAME
```

Alternatively, you can *`return`* the value of `CHARNAME` from the function:

```
def setName(name):
    return name

CHARNAME = setName('1234')
```

Of course this is rather useless and you might as well do `CHARNAME = '1234'`

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
def setName(name):
    global CHARNAME
    CHARNAME = name
    print CHARNAME
```

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-you-set-a-global-variable-in-a-function.htm