# Modifying a variable in Python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a Galaga clone with pygame and I am having issues with using a value in one function that was modified in other function.  I created a very simple version of the code to try to debug it but I have not had any luck.

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

var1 = 10

def function3(var1):

    var1 = var1 + 2


def function1():
    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit:
        function3(var1)

        print(var1)
        clock.tick(5)
function1()
```

My question is (based on this simplified version) how do I display the updated value of var1.  I would like print(var1) to display 10,12,14,16...

My guess is to use a global declaration but the closest question that I found on stackexchange was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884327/python-variable-resetting) and it didn't seem to work with my scenario.

Please note that I'm aware that this increase of var1 could be done with a while loop but a while loop will not work with my actual code.  I would like an answer (or hint) that utilizes this format (as shown above).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: So you want `var1=16` but `print(var1)` to show "10,12,14,16"? Perhaps you want each print to add to what you have already printed?

Comment: return the value of `var1` as well in `function3`. And initialize it in `function1`. Refraining a downvote because Galaga is great.

Comment: whoever downvoted this, please go back to facebook or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use return in your function:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

var1 = 10

def function3(v):
    return v + 2


def function1():
    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit:
        var1 = function3(var1)

        print(var1)
        clock.tick(5)

function1(var1)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm thinking of creating a class as @MK. suggested but return could also work.

Comment: This really is the "correct" way in Python as modifying global variables ruins modularization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is "correct" way of doing what you want:

```
var1 = 10

def function3():
    global var1
    var1 = var1 + 2

print var1
function3()
print var1
```

Your code is modifying local variable var1 which is only defined within your function3.
I put word correct in quotes because global variable is (almost) never a good idea.  If you need state (variable) shared between multiple functions, you could create a class.  Or you could be modern functional and immutable and have the function take a value as argument, modify and return it.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for your quick response!   I'll look into creating a class...